# Java - How does SSL verify certificate revocation status?

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509certificate, certificate-revocation

I know there are two different ways, CRL's and OCSP - I am researching where exactly in Java's SSL source code (openjdk) that these checks are performed.

As far as I can ascertain these checks are performed somewhere within the `X509TrustManager#checkClientTrusted(...)` and most likely passed around with a `PKIXBuilderParameters` object.

Can anybody locate the exact area where SSL initiates the checks on a certificate/chain that runs through the CLR data / OCSP?

An example from other security libraries would also work (such as Spring or Apache Commons)

Comment: whats the reason for your search? - maybe other libraries are interesting too for you.

Comment: Primarily as research to use for developing something similar - viewing an industry standard implementation would be very helpful.

Comment: Bouncy Castle may be an interesting library - an example for an [OCSP request](http://helpcoder.blogspot.de/2009/04/ocsp-and-java.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache uses the library Bouncy Castle for their OCSP and CRL Verifiers. You can find these classes in their [svn repository](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/trunk/java/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/utils/sslcert/).

You find the OCSP-Handling in their [OCSPVerifier](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/trunk/java/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/utils/sslcert/ocsp/OCSPVerifier.java) and the CRL-handling in their [CRLVerifier](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/synapse/trunk/java/modules/transports/core/nhttp/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/transport/utils/sslcert/crl/CRLVerifier.java)